# Github Actions - What am I doing wrong with this conditional step?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I'm creating an action for a Selenium grid instance, it's only supposed to exit if $READY comes back false, $READY is true and we're still getting a failed job!

```yaml
      - name: Get Selenium Grid status variables
        run: |
          echo "READY=$(cURL 'http://localhost:4444/status' | jq '.value.ready')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          NODE_COUNT=$(cURL 'http://localhost:4444/status' | jq '.value.nodes' | jq 'length')

      - name: (DEBUG) Print variables
        env:
          ENV_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(env) }}
          STEP_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
        run: |
          echo "$READY" # true
          echo "${{env.READY}}" # true
          cURL http://localhost:4444/status

      - name: Confirm Grid is up
        if: ${{ env.READY }} == true
        run: echo "Selenium Grid is Ready"
      - name: Exit if Grid is down
        if: ${{ env.READY }} != true
        run: echo "Selenium Grid wasn't ready, ending action" && exit 1
```

[image: Action result]

Any help is appreciated

> Also the runner is Macmini if that's relevant

Comment: Did you try using `if: ${{ env.READY == 'true' }}` and `if: ${{ env.READY != 'true' }}` instead?

Comment: See this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-contexts-to-access-variable-values

Answer (score 1):

You must use `if: ${{ env.READY == 'true' }}` and `if: ${{ env.READY != 'true' }}` as mentioned by @GuiFalourd.

I want also give my opinion, storing environment variables at complex github workflow is not easy to manage, If I had a error, must edit again the workflow file, test the workflow again. Usually I'm wrap it to `bash` script to run a complex job.

As example

```
name: Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Validating Task
        run: |
          # Run some validation task, then store at $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "READY=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
      - name: Execute task if ready
        if: ${{ env.READY == 'true' }}
        run: |
          echo "Executing task !"
          bash ./tools.sh update
          id

      - name: Execute task if not ready
        if: ${{ env.READY != 'true' }}
        run: |
          echo "Not ready!"
          bash ./tools.sh notify
          id
```

Also I'm test the workflows file with https://github.com/nektos/act in github codespace.

Just install and run with `act -W test.yaml`

Output :

```
@anasfanani ➜ /workspaces/act (master) $ act -W test.yaml 
INFO[0000] Using docker host 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock', and daemon socket 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock' 
[Greeting on variable day/testing]   Start image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest
INFO[0000] Parallel tasks (0) below minimum, setting to 1 
[Greeting on variable day/testing]     docker pull image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest platform= username= forcePull=true
[Greeting on variable day/testing] using DockerAuthConfig authentication for docker pull
INFO[0002] Parallel tasks (0) below minimum, setting to 1 
[Greeting on variable day/testing]     docker create image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[] network="host"
[Greeting on variable day/testing]     docker run image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[] network="host"
[Greeting on variable day/testing] ⭐ Run Main actions/checkout@v4
[Greeting on variable day/testing]     docker cp src=/workspaces/act/. dst=/workspaces/act
[Greeting on variable day/testing]   ✅  Success - Main actions/checkout@v4
[Greeting on variable day/testing] ⭐ Run Main Validating Task
[Greeting on variable day/testing]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/1] user= workdir=
[Greeting on variable day/testing]   ✅  Success - Main Validating Task
[Greeting on variable day/testing]   ⚙  ::set-env:: READY=true
[Greeting on variable day/testing] ⭐ Run Main Execute task if ready
[Greeting on variable day/testing]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/2] user= workdir=
| Executing task !
| TOOLS SH CALLED
| uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
[Greeting on variable day/testing]   ✅  Success - Main Execute task if ready
[Greeting on variable day/testing] Cleaning up container for job testing
[Greeting on variable day/testing]   Job succeeded
@anasfanani ➜ /workspaces/act (master) $
```